# EF issue adding entity with list of child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I've been trying to update an entity that will have a list of child entities but for some reason I keep getting the same error and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated. The error is:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Bellow is what I am trying:

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> ChildList { get; set; } = new HashSet<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(12)]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [IgnoreMap]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public async Task<Parent> UpdateParent(Parent Parent)
{
    Parent originalParent = await GetById(Parent.Id, c => c.ChildList);

    Mapper.Map(Parent, originalParent);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return originalParent;
}
```

Also I have noticed that if I don't use automapper and I just map the properties manually it works:

```
private static void MapParentProperties(Parent parent, Parent originalParent)
{
    originalParent.Name = parent.Name;
    originalParent.FullName = parent.FullName;
}
```

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Automapper with EF for a while due to past issues similar to this and lazy load trigger, but I've been digging around into it lately given it seems to have better IQueryable support. I'm not sure if it's still the case, but Automapper had a limitation that mapped child collections would be replaced by default, and with EF this could be treated as new entities being marked for insertion or existing child entities getting "bumped out" of the parent and EF flagging that their FK could not be #nulled. The solution was to tell Automapper to keep the destination collection, then handle those mappings individually. (using the child maps) There might be some additional work needed to handle inserts & deletes in the modified collection.

Something that may help:
http://bzbetty.blogspot.com/2012/06/updating-collections-using-automapper.html